# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided - AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am receiving the following error when trying to access one of my files on S3:

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
        The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
    </Message>
</Error>
```

The image shows normally on my website, but accessing it through my API gives me the error above. Any idea why this would be happening?

***S3 settings:***

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key here'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key here'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket name'
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = 'something.cloudfront.net'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'oby.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
STATIC_S3_PATH = 'media/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'oby.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_S3_PATH = 'static/'

S3_URL = '//{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_ROOT = 'this is fine'
STATIC_ROOT = 'this is fine'
MEDIA_URL = '//{}/{}'.format(AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, STATIC_S3_PATH)
STATIC_URL = '//{}/{}'.format(AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, DEFAULT_S3_PATH)

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = False
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: what does it mean "accessing it through my API gives me the error above"? Give an example for the url you're using please. Also it'd be helpfull if you enumerate which libraries you're using.

Comment: @matagus I'm using the Django Rest Framework for my API. When I say I can't access it from my API, I mean that it displays the S3 url for the image. For example, the url would look something like: `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/s3/...`. When I go to that link, I get the error. However, if I go to the page on my website where the image is being displayed, it shows perfectly. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of reasons. One common problem is the system time on the client. If it is too far from the 'real' time, this error can occur.

Comment: Is there a way to align them to be closer in time?

Comment: Use ntp. Look up the command line for your OS and run it once.  Then try the aws command again